# Find room(s) with maximum guests along with guest count

Tags: matrix

I am looking at this code challenge:

> A hotel has n rooms, numbered from 1 to n.
>
> On a given day, m guests come to visit the hotel. Each guest books a room for some duration (in hours). Rooms are allocated in such a way that, out of all the free rooms, a room with minimum number will be allocated to the guest.
>
> Find the room number(s) that served the maximum number of guests and also tell the guest count.
>
> Guests always come alone, so 1 room will be occupied by only 1 guest at a time.
>
> ### Example
>
> ```
> Guests:[[10, 2], [10,3], [12, 2], [9,3], [11,2], [13,4]] // [start time, duration]
> Number of rooms = 6
> 1 [9, 3]
> 2 [10, 2]
> 3 [10, 3]
> 4 [11, 2]
> 1 [12, 2]
> 2 [13, 4]
> ```
>
> Both room 1 and room 2 served 2 customers each so we have to return rooms as [1, 2] and guest count as 2.
>
> We can assume that end time for a guest's stay will always be in the same day itself. If there are no free rooms when a guest arrives at the hotel, we can ignore that guest as well.
>
> In the above example if the number of rooms is only 2, then when guests [10, 3] and [11, 2] come, we have to discard the guests as all of our rooms are currently occupied. By the time [12, 1] comes we have a room freed up so again we'll allocate the room as per above rules.

I tried sorting the guests based on arrival time and then for each guest, checked all rooms incrementally one by one for allocation. This resulted in overall complexity of O(mlogm + m*n). Is there a way to optimise this further?

Comment: Please don't tag with `dsa` -- your question is not about Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: Why does the example allocate the last customer to room 2 and not to room 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to optimise this further:

1. Store the arrivals as separate entries in a time table keyed by hour, and per hour the list of arriving guests. O().
2. Store the departures as separate entries in a time table keyed by hour, and per hour the list of departing guests. O().
3. Create a min-heap (capacity ) with room numbers, initially with the numbers of all rooms: a room number is in the heap when it is free. O()
4. Create an array ( entries) with per guest the room they are in (if any, else -1). Initially it is filled with -1. O()
5. Create a counter per room ( entries) initialised with all 0. O()
6. Iterate the hours of the day (0 .. 23), and for each hour -- O(1):

   - For each departure at that hour -- O():

     - Retrieve the guest's room number from the array in O(1), and if it is not -1 then add the room number to the heap (to indicate it is now free). O(log)
   - For each arrival at that hour -- O():

     - If the heap is not empty, pull the minimum room number from the heap -- O(log) -- and write this association in the array -- O(1) --, and increment the associated room counter -- O(1).
7. From the counters retrieve the maximum count. O()
8. From the counters retrieve the rooms with that maximum count. O()

This has a worst case time complexity of O( + log)

Implementation in Python:

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def solve(guests, rooms):
    arrivals = [[] for hour in range(25)]
    departures = [[] for hour in range(25)]
    for guest, (start, duration) in enumerate(guests):
        arrivals[start].append(guest)
        departures[start+duration].append(guest)
        
    roomheap = list(range(rooms))
    roomforguest = [-1] * len(guests)
    roomcount = [0] * rooms

    for hour in range(24):
        for guest in departures[hour]:
            if roomforguest[guest] > -1:
                heappush(roomheap, roomforguest[guest])
        for guest in arrivals[hour]:
            if roomheap:
                room = heappop(roomheap)
                roomforguest[guest] = room
                roomcount[room] += 1

    maxcount = max(roomcount)
    return [room for room, count in enumerate(roomcount) if count == maxcount], maxcount
```